# PHPUnit database testing and Travis CI: Can't truncate table

Tags: php, mysql, testing, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm writing PHPUnit tests to test MySQL database filling.  My tests work fine locally, but are failing on Travis CI with the following error:

```
PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Exception: COMPOSITE[TRUNCATE] operation failed on query: 

   TRUNCATE `simple_table`

   using args: Array

   [SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'test.simple_table' doesn't exist]
```

I have a `DatabaseTestCase` parent class and a `FillCommandTest` testing class.

DatabaseTestCase

```
class DatabaseTestCase extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{
    private static $pdo = null;

    private $connection = null;

    /**
     * Construct.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $env = new Environment();

        $this->dsn = "mysql:dbname=". $env->get('DB_DATABASE', 'test') . ";host=" . $env->get('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
        $this->username = $env->get('DB_USERNAME', 'travis');
        $this->password = $env->get('DB_PASSWORD', '');
        $this->db_name = $env->get('DB_DATABASE', 'test');
    }

    /**
     * Get database connection.
     * 
     * @return  PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection
     */
    final public function getConnection()
    {
        if ($this->connection === null) {
            if (self::$pdo == null) {
                self::$pdo = new PDO($this->dsn, $this->username, $this->password);
            }

            $this->connection = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(self::$pdo, $this->db_name);
        }

        return $this->connection;
    }

    /**
     * Get XML dataset.
     * 
     * @param   string $file
     * @return  string
     */
    public function getDataSet($file = 'empty.xml')
    {
        $file = 'tests/datasets/' . $file;

        return $this->createXmlDataSet($file);
    }

    /**
     * Set up the test database table
     * 
     * @param   PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_DefaultDatabaseConnection $connection
     */
    protected function setUpTable($connection)
    {
        $pdo = $connection->getConnection();

        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simple_table (
            id INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
            address VARCHAR(100)
        )";

        $pdo->exec($sql);
    }
}
```

FillCommandTest

```
class FillCommandTest extends DatabaseTestCase
{
    protected $app;

    protected $command;

    protected $command_tester;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->app = new Application();
        $this->app->add(new FillCommand());
        $this->command = $this->app->find('fill');
        $this->command_tester = new CommandTester($this->command);

        parent::setUp();

        $connection = $this->getConnection();
        $this->setUpTable($connection);
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public function test_parse_and_fill_simple_table()
    {
        copy(getcwd() . '/tests/files/FillSimpleTable.php', getcwd() . '/src/Fillers/FillSimpleTable.php');

        copy(getcwd() . '/tests/files/simple.txt', getcwd() . '/src/Files/simple.txt');

        $this->command_tester->execute(array(
            'command' => $this->command->getName(),
            'name' => 'simple_table'
        ));

        $actual = $this->getConnection()->createQueryTable('simple_table', 'SELECT * FROM simple_table');

        $expected = $this->getDataSet('simple_table.xml')->getTable('simple_table');

        $this->assertTablesEqual($expected, $actual);

        unlink(getcwd() . '/src/Fillers/FillSimpleTable.php');

        unlink(getcwd() . '/src/Files/simple.txt');
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, it seems your code is referring to a database called 'test'.

But I am assuming since you are deploying, your database name should be different.  Make sure your .env DB_DATABASE variable reflects the correct one on your production server.

Comment: The package does not have a production database.  Its to be used for filling databases.  So the user would create their own database, then use this package to help them fill it.
For the test, Im trying to create a test database called 'test' and a table called 'simple_table'.  I then want to run it through my code, test the results and truncate the table before the next test.